# Kill process with Java

Tags: java, c++, c, windows

In Windows OS, `` does not seem to gracefully shutdown a process (that is, it does not help in triggering a "shutdown" hook, but I found a solution in C.

Hence, `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new ShutdownHook());` does not trigger at `taskkill /F /PID` command.

The "C" code that works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2) {
        unsigned pid = 0;
        if (sscanf_s(argv[1], "%u", &pid) == 1) {
            FreeConsole(); // AttachConsole will fail if we don't detach from current console
            if (AttachConsole(pid)) {
                //Disable Ctrl-C handling for our program
                SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, TRUE);
                GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

My question here, how can you do this in pure Java, meaning to be build a jar and run it like: `java -jar killprocess.jar 1234` where 1234 is the process id.

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing in the API of the JDK that does this. You need to issue a command of the host operating system via class [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). I think you misunderstand the purpose of the shutdown hook. Please correct me if I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Fireburn -- how is this question different from this one, that your raised earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64181947/java-application-shutdown-kill-hook

Comment: @KevinBoone I think the other post is the one actually asking "which command" this post have the answer but more generally asking about converting the C code so I will edit this and add the "C" tag.

Answer (score 0):

This code will take the first argument as the PID and kill the process

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int tokill = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    
    try {
        String cmd = "taskkill /im "+tokill+" /t /f";
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```